# Java case-insensitive regex matching doesn't work with letter Ñ

Tags: java, regex

Consider this program:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class xx {

    /*
     *  Ñ
     *  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE
     *  Unicode: U+00D1, UTF-8: C3 91
     */
    public static final String BIG_N = "\u00d1";

    /*
     *  ñ
     *  LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE
     *  Unicode: U+00F1, UTF-8: C3 B1
     */
    public static final String LITTLE_N = "\u00f1";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(BIG_N.equalsIgnoreCase(LITTLE_N));
        System.out.println(Pattern.compile(BIG_N, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(LITTLE_N).matches());
    }
}
```

Since Ñ is the upper-case version of ñ, you would expect it to print:

```
true
true
```

but what it actually prints (java 1.7.0_17-b02) is:

```
true
false
```

Why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> By default, case-insensitive matching assumes that only characters in the US-ASCII charset are being matched. Unicode-aware case-insensitive matching can be enabled by specifying the UNICODE_CASE flag in conjunction with this flag.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE

And for completeness; you or (`|`) the flags together.

```
Pattern.compile(BIG_N, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE)
```

Comment: D'oh! Old US-ASCII rears its ugly head again. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I tried to earlier but it was too soon. Then it was time to eat supper. Taco night.